# i want to set counter which automatically increment and decrements the value

Tags: dom

I want to set counter which automatically ++ the value of name like this Email1 Email2 and so on by clicking add field button and further when i click on the remove button it should -- the value of Email in reverse like Email2  Email1 and so on below I'm using the code,

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Email</label>
 <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($team->email);?>" />
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="Email"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
});
 </script>
```

Email is the name of the text field and i want to to increment or decrement this name

Comment: prabhat sinha plzzz help me on the above issue

Answer (score 0):

Just changed following code:

```
<input type="text" class="del" id="' + name + '"/>
```

and

```
$(".del").last().parent('div').remove();
```

it will always remove the last element.

Following is the working code Just set the value of text box:

$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        var name = "Email" + x;
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" class="del" id="' + name + '"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
    var removeLastName = "Email" + x;    
    e.preventDefault(); $(".del").last().parent('div').remove();
    x--;
})
});

Comment: how to increment the name